# Oracle type compare

Tags: oracle, object, types

Oracle & objects:

I have a table that contain more than one type of object (by using inheritance),but i want to 
know the actual type of each (using loop and ?).  Is there a function like `isInstanceOf()` here?

plz provide an example

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the [OF TYPE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10799/adobjbas.htm#sthref262) clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_OBJ AS OBJECT (
  field1  VARCHAR2(20),
  field2  NUMBER(10)
);
```

Then you can use the SYS.ANYDATA type.

```
DECLARE
   t_test_obj TEST_OBJ;
   v_anydata SYS.ANYDATA; 
BEGIN
    t_test_obj := TEST_OBJ('ABC',123);
    v_anydata := SYS.ANYDATA.ConvertObject(t_test_obj);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OBJECT TYPE IS : '||v_anydata.GetTypeName());
END;
```